# AWS SQS SNS protocol using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

The following code allows me to send `SNS` with (queue) `SQS` but i cant seem to choose the protocol like in amazons management console
[image]

* the keys are all random strings

```
<?php
require_once('sdk-1.5.6.2/sdk.class.php');  
$AWS_KEY = "6VVWTU4JDAAKHYB1C3ZN";
$AWS_SECRET_KEY = "GMSCUD8C0QA1QLV9Y3RP2IAKDIZSCHRGKEJSXZ4F";

//create a new SQS queue and grab the queue URL
$sqs = new AmazonSQS(array( "key" => $AWS_KEY, "secret" => $AWS_SECRET_KEY ));
$response = $sqs->create_queue('test-topic-queue');
$queue_url = (string) $response->body->CreateQueueResult->QueueUrl;
$queue_arn = 'arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:ENCQ8gqrAcXv:test-topic-queue';

//create a new SNS topic and grab the topic ARN.
$sns = new AmazonSNS(array( "key" => $AWS_KEY, "secret" => $AWS_SECRET_KEY ));
$response = $sns->create_topic('test-topic');
$topic_arn = (string) $response->body->CreateTopicResult->TopicArn;

//Then give the SNS topic the permission to send messages to the SQS queue. ** allow all principals. SNS doesn't send from your account ID -- it has its own account ID that it sends from.
$queue_url = 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ENCQ8gqrAcXv/test-topic-queue';
$queue_arn = 'arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:ENCQ8gqrAcXv:test-topic-queue';
$topic_arn = 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:ENCQ8gqrAcXv:test-topic';

$policy = new CFPolicy($sqs, array(
        'Version' => '2008-10-17',
        'Id' => 'sampleId',
        'Statement' => array(
                array(
                        'Resource' => $queue_arn,
                        'Effect' => 'Allow',
                        'Sid' => 'rule1',
                        'Action' => 'sqs:*',
                        'Condition' => array(
                                'StringEquals' => array(
                                        'aws:SourceArn' => $topic_arn
                                )
                        ),
                        'Principal' => array(
                                'AWS' => '*'
                        )
                )
        )
));

$response = $sqs->set_queue_attributes($queue_url, array(
        array('Name' => 'Policy', 'Value' => $policy->get_json())
));


//then subscribe the SQS queue to the SNS topic and grab the subscription ARN.
$queue_arn = 'arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:ENCQ8gqrAcXv:test-topic-queue';
$topic_arn = 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:ENCQ8gqrAcXv:test-topic';
$response = $sns->subscribe($topic_arn, 'sqs', $queue_arn);




// normally here is where you would choose the protocol but this example sends this to SQS
// subscribe ( $topic_arn, $protocol, $endpoint, $opt ) 




$subscription_arn = (string) $response->body->SubscribeResult->SubscriptionArn;
//view the list of subscriptions to verify.
$topic_arn = 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:ENCQ8gqrAcXv:test-topic';

$q = new CFBatchRequest(200);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
{
        $sns->batch($q)->publish($topic_arn, 'Hello world! ' . time());
}
$response = $sns->batch($q)->send();


//receive messages from the queue.
$queue_url = 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ENCQ8gqrAcXv/test-topic-queue';
$response = $sqs->receive_message($queue_url, array(
        'MaxNumberOfMessages' => 10,
));
print_r($response); 


// delete SQS queue
$queue_url = 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ENCQ8gqrAcXv/test-topic-queue'; 
$response = $sqs->delete_queue($queue_url);

?>
```

**question:** where would i choose the protocol? 
[this link](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#i=AmazonSNS) says that `subscribe()` is where `protocol` is defined but the above example sends that to `SQS`

Answer (score 3):

You can use SNS to push to an SMS number, and you can also use SNS to push to an SQS queue. But SQS is not capable of pushing *anything* — including to an SMS number.

Perhaps you have your infrastructure components confused?

Comment: then what is "inside" SQS, i pictured it as a string

Comment: SQS contains messages. _You_ put messages in, and _you_ pull messages out… but SQS doesn't _do_ anything other than store the messages. SQS isn't a _push_ model — it's a _pull_ model. SNS does pushing.

Answer (score 2):

Subscribe method has the following signature

```
subscribe ( $topic_arn, $protocol, $endpoint, $opt )
```

If you what to subscribe using SMS as protocol then do the following

```
$response = $sns->subscribe($topic_arn, 'sms', $phone_no);
```

where `$phone_no(String)` is the phone number of the sms enabled device

The different protocols currently supported are http, https, email, email-json, sms and sqs based on the protocol you have to change the `$endpoint` parameter passed to the subscribe method.

Checkout the full documentation for [subscribe method](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonSNS/subscribe)

Comment: but then how does this get sent to SQS?

Comment: i am trying to send SMS using SQS.  in my sample code, it seems to send to SQS but im not understanding where i can choose the protocol

Comment: I dont think thats possible. SMS protocol is part of SNS and can only be used for SNS notification. If you want to send SMS for items in SQS then you will have to use some other sms service together with some code to consume items from sqs.

Comment: You can configure sns to send sms directly as I said earlier or you would configure sns to send the notification to sqs then you will have to create a process which will consume items from sqs and send sms using some sms provider.